# how to access the super class from a child class in php

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have 3 classes with the following inheritance structure:

```
   <?php
     class admin {
       function __construct($module){
         echo $module;
       }
     }

     class user_admin extends admin {
       function __construct(){
         parent::__construct('user');
       }
     }

     class sales_admin extends user_admin {
       function __construct(){
         parent::__construct('sales');
       }
     }
```

You'll notice that the sales_admin extends the user_admin, this is a nescessary step. When I run this code,

```
$a = new sales_admin;
```

it will echo "user", because it passes the "sales" string to the user_admin which doesn't accept a constructor.

Is there a way to access the constructor of the parent above it without changing the user_admin, which I don't have control over?

Comment: Need actual code and the problem you are having.  Are you trying to echo 'sales'?  You should have getters and setters that should allow you to change other things, unless the parent is doing things statically and then your just out of luck and defeating the purpose of OO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reference the class directly:

```
class sales_admin extends user_admin
{
    function __construct()
    {
        admin::__construct('sales');
    }
}

$a = new sales_admin; // outputs 'sales'
```

Since user_admin extends admin, and sales_admin extends user_admin, sales_admin will have scope of the admin constructor

Comment: sales_admin can call admin::__construct(), but the fact that sales_admin is a descendant of admin is not the reason. On the scope argument, admin's constructor is public and therefore can be accessed anywhere.

Comment: In this example it could be either, you're right, but in a normal application the `admin` class would have to be included if `sales_admin` wasn't a descendant. My mind went one way, yours went the other. Good for the OP to know both, I suppose :)

Comment: And to clarify, sales_admin cannot extend admin if the admin class has not been included.

Comment: It doesn't, it extends user_admin, which extends admin. We have to assume user_admin has visibility to the admin class.

Answer (score 0):

```
//super implimentation php

class object extends other_object {
    function __construct(){
        $this->super();
    }

    function super() {
        $parentClass = get_parent_class($this);
        $this->$parentClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sales_admin knows it has a parent because it is extending user_admin. However, how can sales_admin possibly know if user_admin has a parent? In PHP, sales_admin does not have a way of knowing -- unless you cheat with reflection.

An option that you do have is to borrow admin's constructor. You can do this by calling `admin::__construct('sales');`. Note that you can borrow the method of any class this way, regardless of the inheritance tree -- that is, the caller does not have to be a descendant of the callee.

Despite this option, I would recommend changing your design in such a way that you can avoid the inheritance altogether.